# Arduino as Keyboard HID: Program runs differently in Keyboard/Programming mode

Tags: c++, arduino, hid

I am trying to make a keyboard HID using my Arduino Uno. My Arduino 1) lights the red LED when setting up connection to the input (something simulating a key press_ and turns it off when connection is established;  2) lights the blue LED when input is triggered, sends the emulated keyboard signal through the Serial once, and turns off the LED when the input is untriggered. My program seems to work, turning on the red LED for about 0.5s at startup, lighting up the blue LED and sends signal as intended when outside input is triggered.

However after I short the Arduino to clear the original hex and flash the hex file required to help my PC identify the Arduino as an HID keyboard using [Freematics Builder](https://github.com/stanleyhuangyc/Freematics/releases/tag/builder), the program no longer works as intended. The red LED no longer turns on at startup; the blue LED always dimly light up and does not respond to outside input triggers. I tried multiple hex file versions ([one version](https://github.com/coopermaa/USBKeyboard/blob/master/firmware/Arduino-keyboard-0.3.hex), [another version](https://github.com/SyllogismRXS/syllo-arduino/blob/master/scripts/dfu/Arduino-usbserial-uno.hex)) but all of them behave the same.

Am I using a bad version of hex file? Am I doing anything wrong?

P.S. Simplified code:

```cpp
// #includes

Adafruit_MPR121 cap = Adafruit_MPR121(); // input

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define KEY_1 0x59
#define KEY_2 0x5a
#define KEY_3 0x5b
#define KEY_4 0x5c
#define KEY_5 0x5d
// ... Keycodes

void press_key(int key) {
  uint8_t buf[8] = {0};
  buf[2] = key;
  Serial.write(buf, 8);
  buf[2] = 0;
  Serial.write(buf, 8);
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT); // blue LED
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); // red LED
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) delay(10); 

  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  if (!cap.begin(0x5A)) { // Wait until established connection
    while (1);
  }
  digitalWrite(3, LOW); // turn off red LED

  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  if (input_is_valid()) {
    if (input_triggered()) {
      press_key(corresponding_key);
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH); // light blue LED
    } else { // input_untriggered
      digitalWrite(2, LOW); // turn off blue LED
    }
  }
  
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what freematics has to do with making ahid keyboard?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Freematics is the software used to flash the hex file into Arduino.

Comment: Why UNO? There are variants with atmega32u4 (leonardo, micro, pro micro, ..) with native USB and it works...

Comment: @KIIV My school's lab only has uno... I wanted to do a leonardo that has built-in Keyboard emulations well...

Answer (score 0):

I used Atmel Flip for the flashing and it worked. The versions of hex files I used is in [this tutorial](https://techtotinker.blogspot.com/2020/07/tutorial-how-to-use-arduino-uno-as-hid.html?m=1). After shorting the Arduino and before flashing, check the Arduino in your Device Manager. If it shows something like atmega16u2 under other devices, follow the extra step in the above blog to install the driver from Atmel. After these steps you may need a few tries before successfully loading the hex.